# I get an error when I create a MATERIALIZED VIEW

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I want to create MATERIALIZED VIEW to speed up queries.

This is my method:

I have 4 tables and create a MATERIALIZED VIEW:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW v_tbmv 
AS 
SELECT id,name tname, bname, mname, vname 
FROM type 
  left join(
    select  berand.type_id, berand.name bname,mname,vname 
    from berand 
      left join (
        select   model.name mname, versions.name vname,model.berand_id 
        from model 
          left join  versions on versions.model_id = model.id
     ) m on berand.id = m.berand_id
  ) b on  b.type_id = type.id;
```

Comment: What error? And please, don't use images, just plain text.

Comment: I understand English is not an easy language for everyone and thank you for trying. I just want to give one tip which is to use google translate. It will make it clearer for us and you will get more/better answers.

Comment: An error was specified in the title, but is not posted in full in the body of the question.